# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PagesController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

My PagesController - Every time I click certain buttons on my page it gives me this error.

Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PagesController] does not exist.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\WorkWithPage;
use App\Models\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('admin');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->isAdminOrUser()) {
            $pages = Page::paginate(5);
        } else {
            $pages = Auth::user()->pages()->paginate(5);
        }
        return view('admin.pages.index', ['pages' => $pages]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('admin.pages.create')->with(['model' => new Page()]);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(WorkWithPage $request)
    {
        //
        Auth::user()->pages()->save(new Page($request->only([
            'title','url','content'])));

        return redirect()->route('pages.index')->with('status', 'The page has been created.');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Page  $page
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Page $page)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->cant('update', $page)) {
            return redirect()->route('pages.index');
        }

        return view('admin.pages.edit', ['model' => $page]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Page  $page
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(WorkWithPage $request, Page $page)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->cant('update', $page)) {
            return redirect()->route('pages.index');
        }
        $page->fill($request->only([
            'title','url','content']));

        $page->save();
        return redirect()->route('pages.index')->with('status', 'The page has been updated');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Page  $page
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Page $page)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->cant('delete', $page)) {
            return redirect()->route('pages.index');
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the page controller, the users controller, the routes, the providers for the last 2 days I cant do anything evene when I temporarily clear the error it comes back. The course I'm using for this doesn't show me what the problem is I wanted it over and over from the end to the beginning and the beginning to the end.

Here is the route file as well

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/admin', function() {
    return view('admin.index');
})->middleware('admin');

Route::resource('/admin/pages', 'App\Http\ControllersAdmin\PagesController', ['except' => [
    'show'
]]);

Route::resource('/admin/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UsersController', ['except' => [
    'create','store','show'
]]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: I think this is a mistake in your route file. Looks like you are missing an `\\` at the start of your controller namespace. Could you add the route file, and what version of Laravel you are using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 8, I just added the route file

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: `App\Http\ControllersAdmin\PagesController` - how should this be resolved to your controller that is stored in a different namespace?

Comment: I would advise you to use the new route syntax: `Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);` . It would fix the namespace problem. Don't forget the `use` statement for the Controllers

Comment: If you add error trace its help more..

Answer (score 1):

If the class is in quotes, then you would use the path relative to `\App\Http\Controllers`

```
Route::resource('/admin/pages', 'Admin\PagesController', ['except' => [
    'show'
]]);

Route::resource('/admin/users', 'Admin\UsersController', ['except' => [
    'create','store','show'
]]);
```

Or you can use the full class path

```
Route::resource('/admin/pages', \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PagesController::class, ['except' => [
    'show'
]]);

Route::resource('/admin/users', \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UsersController::class, ['except' => [
    'create','store','show'
]]);
```

Comment: Not sure why but the first route comes up with an error and it needs a comma, sorry I am quite the beginner with PHP and laravel

Comment: Oops, the full class paths needed double-colons, not single colons. Which first route were you having problems with, the quoted class or the unquoted class?

Comment: Just tried it but it seems to be giving me the same error. Maybe there's a problem in a different folder

Comment: What is the full error, complete with file and line info?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->group(function() {
    Route::resource('/admin/pages', 'PagesController');
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Not sure why it isn't working but it came up with the same error maybe something in another file is the problem but I don't even know where to look I looked at all the controllers, providers and routes no clue what the problem is